# Geopandas - Trying to change values in a cell only works if the column is NoneType

Tags: python, geopandas, geopackage

I'm trying to open a Geopackage to add a column (count of members) there and fill those cells according to the count of members in a specific area.

If I create the column as 'None', everything works fine, except that QGIS doesn't recognize those values as integer but as String (leads to problems when trying to classify when symbolizing everything).

If I change it so that the column is created as integer, the values won't be filled and every cell has the value '0' then (standard integer value).

```
gdf = gpd.read_file("file.gpkg")
gdf["member_count"] = None

agg = {'Berlin' : 25}
for index, row in gdf.iterrows():

    if row["name"] in agg:
        row["member_count"] = agg[row["name"]]


gdf.crs = {'init' : 'epsg:25832'}
gdf.to_file("data/test.gpkg", driver="GPKG")
```

With this piece of code, the cells will be filled with the value which is in the dictionary 'agg' (only if the value from another column 'name' is found in the dict).
If I change 'None' in line 2 to 'int()' or '0' all cells have the value 0 and won't be filled with the corresponding value from the dict.

So with the piece of code above, I get something like this, with the problem that QGIS doesn't recognize the member_count as an integer column.

```
         suid  ... member_count
0    07334013  ...      None
1    07337005  ...      None
2    07334008  ...      None
3    06431018  ...      None
4    06431021  ...         3
5    08226080  ...      None
6    07332025  ...         2
7    07337501  ...      None
8    08226056  ...      None
9    08225116  ...      None
10   08226086  ...      None
11   08226020  ...      None
12   08226059  ...         3
13   08226003  ...         1
```

After changing None in line 2 to 'int()' or '0', I get this:

```
         suid  ... member_count
0    07334013  ...         0
1    07337005  ...         0
2    07334008  ...         0
3    06431018  ...         0
4    06431021  ...         0
5    08226080  ...         0
6    07332025  ...         0
7    07337501  ...         0
8    08226056  ...         0
9    08225116  ...         0
10   08226086  ...         0
11   08226020  ...         0
12   08226059  ...         0
13   08226003  ...         0
```

Comment: Is the expected output like your first result but replace all None with 0?
Also is it possible to share your "file.gpkg" so we can try your code

Comment: Yes and no. My expected output is, that all the 'None' are 0, but also that the data type of the column is "Integer" and not "String". With String as data type, QGIS handles the classified values in a wrong way.

As for the file:
http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/web_download/vg/vg250_0101/utm32s/shape/vg250_0101.utm32s.shape.ebenen.zip
Download this and then under
vg250_0101.utm32s.shape.ebenen/vg250_ebenen/VG250_GEM.shp
That's what I used (converted to GPKG with QGIS).

Comment: Note that in the SHP the columns have slightly different names than in my script. 'name' is called 'GEN' there.